# Cannot view close votes after voted-for duplicate is deleted

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I [came across a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053056/) earlier that I flagged to close as a duplicate, the poster had asked a [virtually identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050422/) an hour before.

Whilst I had voted to close as a duplicate, I believe there was another vote reason on the question too.

Strange thing is, the poster has since deleted the original question that I voted as duplicate and I can now see no close votes at all on the new question, though the auto-generated `possible duplicate of...` comment remains on the question.

Below is the capture where I expected to see `close(n)`, but shows only `close`:

[image: no-close-count]

If I attempt to close again, the dialog box shows that I've already voted, but doesn't show the reasons. I would've expected for the duplicate count to either show in the blue box, or have been deleted and allow me to select again. I would also expect what I recall was an additional close reason to show a count in a blue box, but the whole thing is empty:

[image: no-close-reason]

Is this behaviour expected? Why can I no longer see the number of close votes on the question?

Comment: The close vote being removed makes sense since you can't close as a dupe of a deleted question. But I guess the comment should also be removed automatically at the same time

Comment: @codeMagic that makes sense if it *had* been removed (the fact it tells me I've already voted suggests otherwise), but then why can't I vote again? It's still a poor question and I could probably find another reason.

Comment: That's another good question. I wish we could vote multiple times under certain conditions